# Getting the Navbar to collapsed when on mobile devices instead of ipad portrait - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

Does anyone have any idea on how to get the `navbar` to collapsed when on mobile devices only, instead of iPad (portrait).

I have tried searching for the answer but all I have found is how to make the Navbar come in sooner not later.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure it from here for example:
http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system

```
@grid-float-breakpoint
```

Adjust @grid-float-breakpoint to screen-xs-min.

This requires you to compile and download (button on the bottom) again and replace the bootstrap css in your folder.

Comment: Thank you for that, i shall try that straight away as soon as the bootstrap website is back up and running. I will let you know of my process.